# how to create fake symlinks when copying to CIFS share with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync, cifs, symbolic-link, symlink

So I have to backup lot's of data to a company server. And it creates a fair share of symbolic links. I'm on a Linux Machine, and the backup server is accessed via CIFS, which does not support symbolic links. And there is nothing I can do about it.

So I thought I could create 'fake symlinks' which would contain the information where they were pointing at in case somebody (me or sb else) in the future has to access the backup?

Has anybody done sth like this? What would be the best solution? Or is there a better approach of which I don't know?  I am glad about any solution!

Comment: See the **mfsymlinks** option in the mount.cifs man page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Windows systems do support symlinks, they are just rarely used.

If that doesn't work, see `man mount.cifs`:

> sfu
>   When the CIFS Unix Extensions are not negotiated, attempt to create device files and fifos in a format compatible with Services for Unix (SFU)

Comment: Thanks, I had read that, but AFAIU, this is not in my power as it has to be enabled server-side?

Comment: Did you try that option on the client?